# Writing VB script under HP's QTP-11

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm still a novice at QTP (still learning even the GUI) and I need to write this VB script under it:

> Write a QTP script that:
>
> 1. Browse to Yahoo mailbox
> 2. Perform registration process to Yahoo if this is a new user
> 3. Perform log in to yahoo mailbox if it is existing user
> 4. Send new mail to valid Mailbox
>
>    - Use English version for the yahoo mailbox.
>    - Use only one action and Implement the code with public sub 
>        procedure and unique Data table 
>        for  the test    (don't use default 
>        QTP Data table)

Any directions and/or suggestions will be gladley accepted.

Thanks

Comment: Try going through the tutorial first to get your feet wet with QTP. You may want to consider getting some formal training as well. Then attack this problem. Try it out! If you then have a specific question or problem, post that here.

Comment: Appears like a "do my homework/certclass answers for me please" question to me. If some RTFM and googlin' won't do, the answers here won't either.

Answer (score 0):

Well simple Record action did the trick, but there is no use of public sub procedure and unique Data table.

Is that called **a valid test** ? Is the only VBS code of this action is the code in the Expert view ?

[image]

THNX

Comment: It's certainly not a valid test, since you are only performing navigation steps, and have not added any validation of test results.

Comment: I disagree -- well,, the navigation steps implicitely validate the flow of execution. If the GUI elements cannot be identified correctly during script execution, a FAILED step will be logged. Which is kind of implicit validation of the flow of execution flow in the web interface.